# Using grep, awk, etc. to filter command output

Tags: 11.10, grep, command-line, output

I'll use `route` as an example.

```
route -n
```

The above outputs routing information. The top row is your active connection. I can manipulate the output to only the second column by doing:

```
route -n | awk '{print $2}'
```

**Now, how can I filter by row?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To print a particular line you can use `sed`:

```
route -n | sed -n 2p
```

to print second line.

### `sed`, what is

I will give a short and incomplete explanation of what is `sed`. For a complete description I suggest to see `sed` info pages (run `info sed`).

`sed` mean ***s****tream* ***ed****itor*, i.e. an editor that can act on a stream (or pipe) of text data, though it can act also on files; substantially this mean that (differently from `ed`) it can never turn back to a previous line.

`sed`, as `awk` reads one line at a time and apply a script to that line to possibly modify it. At the end of the script, by default the modified line is output to stdout. Then `sed` go on the the next line.

A script is a sequence of pair address-command, if the line match the address then the command is executed.

The typical use of `sed` is to perform a substitution of a pattern with something, e.g.

```
command | sed 's/ *$//'
```

here the string between single quotes is the script, consisting of a single address-command pair. The address is missing (it would appear before the `s`), in such a case the command is applied by default to all input lines. `s` is the command and the rest of the string are command specific instructions, saying "substitute 0 or more occurrence (`*`) of a space ( ) character at end on line (`$`) with nothing (i.e. remove them)".

Other useful command are `p` and `d`. The `p` command print the current line, this is useful in combination with the `-n` option, that modify the default behavior to print the current line at end of script. So in

```
sed -n '2p'
```

the script is the string `2p` consisting on the address `2` and the command `p`, so the line 2 will be printed, all other line instead will not be printed, due to the `-n` option.

The `d` command delete a line, for example

```
    sed '3,6d'
```

would delete all lines from the third to the sixth. `3,6` is an address range. I observe that in this case one should not use the `-n` option, because we want to print all other lines.

Last thing, an address could be a pattern, like in

```
sed -n '/^#/p'
```

this command would print all lines beginning (`^`) with a `#` character.

Comment: That's very easy! Could you please explain what the p is for?

Comment: @DarkSlipstream: I added a short description of `sed` in general, and of the `p` command in particular.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter IN a row by piping to grep and finding a row that starts with your IP address  of interest, for example, if you want to see the row for 192.168.1.1, you would do:

```
$ route | grep ^192.168.1.0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     2      0        0 wlan0
```

The '^' mark means "line-starts-with'. So you could be more generic with:

```
$ route | grep ^192.168.1
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     2      0        0 wlan0
192.168.111.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to tell awk what lines you want, e.g.

```
route -n | awk '/^192.168/ {print $2}'
```

will output the seconds column of all rows that start with `192.168`

Answer (score 0):

an awk answer could also look something like:

```
$0 ~ ( /matchthis/ ) { print $2 }
```

$0 simply refers to the whole row/line

sed and awk can be a very powerful combination

regular expressions are worth while to master